# How to align actionbar tabs at center

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want to centre align the action bar tab icons in a swipe-able view pager. Apparently the icons are centred in target versions greater than 15 but the height of action bar is fixed aparently its a 
[reported bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41792). So I am using target SDK version 15 and able to set the desired height of action bar but the icons are [left aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXvG8.jpg).

Style used for the activity

```
    <style name="ThemeHoloWithActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">200dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:minHeight">200dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

Code for the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(tabsIcons[i])
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
}
```

tldr: **I want to centre align swipeable tab icons in action bar with a customised height, sdk version <16 lets me change the height but not alignment. version >16 aligns icons properly but can't have a custom height.**